# Search Query in cakePHP 1.2

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have this query:

```
$conditions = array(
            'editore LIKE' => "%$e%",
            'titolo LIKE' => "%$t%"
        );
        if (isset($autore_diviso))
            $conditions[] = array('autori LIKE ? AND ?' => array("%$autore1%","%$autore2%"));                   
        else
            $conditions[]=array('autori LIKE' => "%$a%");
        if (!$anno&&!$anno2) // I HAVE TO CHANGE THIS - if the user does not insert any year
            $conditions=$conditions;
        else {
        if (!$anno)
            $conditions[] = array('anno <=' => "$anno2");          
        if (!$anno2)
            $conditions[] = array('anno >=' => "$anno");
        }
        if ($anno&&$anno2)
            $conditions[] = array('anno BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($anno,$anno2));
```

Where anno mean year, editore means publisher and titolo means title. 

It's not working the search for exactly 2 authors.

If I debug $conditions, I have for example:

```
Array (
[editore LIKE] => %%
[titolo LIKE] => %%
[0] => Array
    (
        [autori LIKE ? AND ?] => Array
            (
                [0] => %massi%
                [1] => %palu%
            )

    ) )
```

But the result is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you add elements to arrays in PHP. Also, there's no need to use explicit `AND`, that's the default. It's needed only if there would otherwise be multiple identical array keys.

```
$conditions = array(
    'autori LIKE ? AND ?' => array("%$autore1%","%$autore2%"), 'editore LIKE' => "%$e%",
    'titolo LIKE' => "%$t%"
);

if (!$anno)
    $conditions[] = array('anno <=' => "$anno2");          

if (!$anno2)
    $conditions[] = array('anno >=' => "$anno");

if ($anno&&$anno2)
    $conditions[] = array('anno BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($anno,$anno2));
```

Comment: I'm getting close, but it's not working the search for 2 authors, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED with this code:

```
$conditions = array(
        'editore LIKE' => "%$e%",
        'titolo LIKE' => "%$t%"
    );
    if (isset($autore_diviso))
        $conditions[] = array('autori LIKE ? AND autori LIKE?' => array("%$autore1%","%$autore2%"));                    
    else
        $conditions[]=array('autori LIKE' => "%$a%");
    if (!$anno&&!$anno2)    // Da sistemare.
        $conditions=$conditions;
    else {
    if (!$anno)
        $conditions[] = array('anno <=' => "$anno2");          
    if (!$anno2)
        $conditions[] = array('anno >=' => "$anno");
    }
    if ($anno&&$anno2)
        $conditions[] = array('anno BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($anno,$anno2));
    debug($conditions);
```